# .each not working on an Array. But .isArray returns true?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have created an object which contains a few items, including one which contains multiple objects each of which contains an array.  Here is how it is structured.

```
$.myVar = {
    cp : "",
    ps : {
        m1 : ["001", "002", "003"],
        m2 : ["002", "004"]
    }
};
```

My scripts keep crashing saying that $.myVar.ps["m1"] has no method each.

When I got into Chrome's console to investigate, I run the following and get the displayed output.

```
$.myVar.ps["m1"]
["001", "002", "003"]
$.myVar.ps["m1"].each( function (i, p) {alert(i)})
TypeError: Object 001,002,003 has no method 'each'
```

Also if I run the following, it proves that m1 is an array.

```
$.isArray($.myVar.ps["m1"])
true
```

So it seems to agree with m1 is an array, but it refuses to treat it as such.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`each` is not a native `Array` method; it is a method of jQuery objects, i.e. those created by the `$` function. You can either do

```
$($.myVar.ps.m1).each(function (i, el) { /* ... */ });
```

(not recommended, because it creates an unnecessary jQuery object when it wraps the array in `$(...)`) or you can just use `$.each`:

```
$.each($.myVar.ps.m1, function (i, el) { /* ... */ });
```

The most recommended route, if you are using a modern browser (IE >=9), or using [es5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim), is to use the standard `Array.prototype.forEach` method:

```
$.myVar.ps.m1.forEach(function (el, i) { /* ... */ });
```

Note the different argument order (IMO better since you can then leave out the index if you don't need it).

Answer (score 7):

`.each` is only defined for jQuery objects. For pure Javascript arrays, [use the "static method" `$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

```
$.each($.myVar.ps["m1"], function(i,p) { alert(i); });
```

Answer (score -2):

each is not a method of an array in javascript.
try:

```
$($.myVar.ps["m1"]).each
```

Comment: Don't construct invalid jQuery objects; use `$.each()` instead.